# python regex doesn't work with special characters after \b, like r"\b@"

Tags: python, regex, special-characters

just like the title said,when the regex is `r"\b@"`, `r"\b#"` or else like that, the string `"blabla @blabla"` will not match the pattern.

in python code:

```
re.findall(r"\b@", "blabla @blabla")
```

and return `[ ]`

this totally make me confused, anyone knows what happened here

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because there isn't a word character exists before `@`. First you have to understand the working of `\b` (which matches the boundary exists between a word character `\w` and a non-word character `\W` or vice-versa).

Here the character exists before `@` is `space` which is not a word character. So it won't match that particular `@` symbol.

May be you could try `\B@` where `\B` does the opposite of `\b`

```
>>> re.findall(r"\B@", "blabla @blabla")
['@']
>>> re.findall(r"\b@", "blabla s@blabla")
['@']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it.